# Schur complement of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

> Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and its inverse be partitioned $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> A_{11} & A_{12}\\
> A_{21} & A_{22}\\
> \end{pmatrix},\:\:
> A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
> \tilde{A_{11}} & \tilde{A_{12}}\\
> \tilde{A_{21}} & \tilde{A_{22}}\\
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   where $A_{11}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ and $\tilde{A_{11}}\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$.
>
> a.) Show that if, $S = A_{22} - A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}$, the Schur complement of $A$ with respect to $A_{11}$ exists then $A$ is nonsingular iff $S$ is nonsingular.
>
> b.) Show that $S^{-1} = \tilde{A_{11}}$.

Attempted solution a.) The Schur complement arises as a result of performing a block Gaussian elimination by multiplying the matrix $A$ from the right with the block lower triangular matrix $$L = \begin{pmatrix}
I_n & 0\\
-A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & I_m\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $I_n$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix. 
\begin{align*}
AL &= \begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
I_{n} & 0\\
-A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & I_m\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & A_{12}\\
0 & A_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
I_n & A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}\\
0 & I_m\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} - A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21} & 0\\
0 & A_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
As you can see after multiplication with the matrix $L$ the Schur complement appears in the upper $n\times n$ block. I am not really sure where to go from here any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take determinants and you have finished (apart from the difference with respect to the problem statement that you are considering the Schur complement of $A_{22}$ instead of that of $A_{11}$).